# Why "CLLocationCoordinate2D location2 = [self adressLocation“ isn't working

Tags: ios, mkmapview

The code should do an adress search. The line `CLLocationCoordinate2D location2 = [self adressLocation` isn't working. It's saying "Invalid Initializer". What could be wrong?

```
-(IBAction) search {
    MKCoordinateRegion region;
    MKCoordinateSpan span;
    span.latitudeDelta = 0.4; 
    span.longitudeDelta = 0.4;  

    CLLocationCoordinate2D location2 = [self adressLocation]; 

    region.span = span;
    region.center = location2;
    Mark adr = [[Mark alloc] initWithCoordinate:location2];
    [mapView addAnnotation:adr];
}

-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) adressLocation {
    NSString * urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://maps.google.com/maps/geo?q=%@&output=csv",[suchFeld.text stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSString * locationString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&fileError];
    NSArray * listItems = [locationString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
    double latitude2 = 0.0;
    double longitude2 = 0.0;
    if ([listItems count] >= 4 && [[listItems objectAtIndex:0] isEqualToString:@"200"])
    {
        latitude2 = [[listItems objectAtIndex:2] doubleValue];
        longitude2 = [[listItems objectAtIndex:3] doubleValue];
    } else {
        // error    
    CLLocationCoordinate2D location2;
    location2.latitude = latitude2;
    location2.longitude = longitude2;
    return location2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `adressLocation` method is probably not declared in the .h file and since the method is defined after the code calling it, the compiler gives that error.  Add this to the .h file:

```
-(CLLocationCoordinate2D) adressLocation;
```

Some separate issues:

In the `search` method, you have `Mark adr = [[Mark alloc]...`.
This should be `Mark *adr = [[Mark alloc]...` (note asterisk).

Also in the `search` method, you need to do `[adr release];` after the `addAnnotation` line.

Finally, `adressLocation` does not return a value in all cases.
It only does a `return` in the else-part.  It needs to return a value in the if-part also.

Comment: Instead of adding to the .h, you could instead declare it in a class extension at the top of the file. This will preserve the "private" nature of the method while still forward-declaring it.